# group of permutation - cycles of length $n$ - order of generated group

Tags: group-theory, permutations

We have all cycles of length $n$.
For example when $n=4$ our set is following form:
$$G = \{(1234);(1243);(1342);(1324);(1432);(1423)\} $$
Our task is to find order of the group generated by the set $G$.

We know, that $|G|\ge (n-1)!$, but I have no clue how to begin.

Try to help me, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(1234)(1243)=(132)(4)$$
and so on, hence all the $3$-cycles belong to the generated group, giving $A_n\subseteq \langle G\rangle$. If $n$ is odd, then $$\langle G\rangle = A_n$$
since no element of $S_n$ with sign $-1$ can belong to $\langle G \rangle$. On the other hand, if $n$ is even there is $\sigma\in\langle G\rangle$ such that $\operatorname{sign}(\sigma)=-1$, so $|\langle G\rangle|>\frac{n!}{2}$, so the generated group is the whole $S_n$:

$$\langle G \rangle = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} S_n&\text{if}&n\equiv 0\pmod{2},\\ A_n&\text{if}&n\equiv 1\pmod{2}.\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: I agree with even all :) But I have doubts. "so the generated group is the whole $S_n$ "  Why ? must be $|\langle G\rangle| > \frac{n!}{2}\wedge |\langle G\rangle| | n! $ but I don't see that $n!$ is only possibility.

Comment: The 3-cycles generates $A_n$, hence the subgroup generated by $G$ has at least $n!/2$ elements, all of them with sign $+1$. If in $\langle G \rangle$ there is an "odd" element, $\langle G \rangle$ has more elements than $A_n$, hence it must be $S_n$ since the order of a subgroup must divide the order of a group, and $m$ has no divisors bigger than $m/2$ except $m$ itself.

Answer (score 2):

Note that any subgroup of $S_n$ generated by a complete set of cycles of length $n$ will be a normal subgroup. For $n\gt 4$ there are just two possibilities - $A_n$ or $S_n$ (the trivial subgroup is impossible).

If $n$ is odd, the cycles which generate the group are all even permutations, and can't generate an odd permutation, so the group is $A_n$. If $n$ is even, the cycles are odd permutations, so the group they generate contains an odd permutation, and must be $S_n$.

For $n\leq 4$ it is necessary to use a different approach (e.g. direct computation in a small group).

Note that essentially the same proof applies when the generators are a complete set of elements of any conjugacy class in $S_n$. However, when $n=4$ the elements conjugate to $(12)(34)$ generate the normal subgroup of order $4$ - so this approach cannot work in  general for order $4$.

Comment: "and must be $S_n$"- why ?

Comment: @xawey Because $A_n$ contains only even permutations, so a nontrivial normal subgroup containing an odd permutation must be the whole group.